# Individual Users authentication type, is adding strange values inside the web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have created a new asp.net mvc 5 web project , and i use the Individual users authentication type.

but when i checked the web.config i found the following :-

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
```

So i am not sure what does these mean:-

- `<authentication mode="None" />`
- `<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC5 doesn't use forms authentication it uses the OWIN middleware. The node `<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />` removes the HTTP module.

Consequently, the `authentication mode="None"` is set to `None` because you are not using any of the *old* authentication providers. If you had created an intranet application as opposed to individual accounts you would see `authentication mode="Windows"`

[See this for more info](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/)